# JS замена значения нажатой клавиши на другое

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, как можно заменить значение нажатой клавиши на другую, например, на ходу изменить регистр. Пытался это сделать через изменение свойств объекта события  keydown, если все правильно понимаю то оно предшествует вставки символа в поле, а потом уже идет keyup. Еще была мысль искусственно вызвать прекратить событие, и вызвать новое но с другой клавишей но не знаю как можно в вызываемое событие вложить объект и тем более с какими свойствами. Как это можно реализовать или есть какая то альтернатива для решения этой задачи?

Comment: А измените лучше "кнопки" на "клавиши", потому что неочевидно по названию вопроса, что речь идет именно о клавишах клавиатуры, а не о кнопках в веб-интерфейсе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var el = document.getElementById('a');
el.onkeypress=function(e){
if(!e)e=window.event;
var k = e.key;
if(!k)k=String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
k = (k.toLowerCase()==k)?k.toUpperCase():k.toLowerCase(); // меняем регистр

if('number'==typeof el.selectionStart){
 var v = el.value;
 var sel1 = el.selectionStart;
 el.value = el.value.substr(0,el.selectionStart) + k + el.value.substr(el.selectionEnd);
 el.selectionStart=el.selectionEnd=sel1+k.length;
} else {
 // выделение в IE не работает, так что просто добавляем в конец
 el.value += k;
}

// что-то из этого не нужно.
if(e.preventDefault)e.preventDefault();
if(e.stopPropagation)e.stopPropagation();
e.cancelBubble = true;
return false;
};
```

```html
<input id="a"/>
```

Всё с заменой не так просто.

`keydown` и `keyup` более, так сказать, "низкоуровневые" - они вызываются именно в моменты нажатия и отпускания клавиши.

Нужное для замены событие, **`keypress`**, вызывается когда **должен напечататься один символ**. Например, при нажатии Shift `keypress` не выстрелит, а если нажать и держать какую-нибудь букву - событие `keypress` будет стрелять на каждый появившийся символ.

Увы, симулировать нажатие кнопки пользователем в браузере невозможно.

Событие-то создать и выстрелить им в элемент можно (`new KeyboardEvent("keyup",{"key":"a"})`, как подксказывает Alex Krass), только оно не приведет к появлению символа в поле ввода (или редактируемом блоке), хотя и вызовет все javascript-обработчики (если они есть).

Выход один - работать с выделением. Нужно рассчитать, что произойдет с текстом (и позицией курсора) в поле после нажатия кнопки. И если в случае с `<input>`'ом и не-IE всё более-менее просто, то с `<div contentEditable>` и со старыми IE всё очень плохо.

Кстати, пользователь может ещё вставить что-нибудь из буфера (событие paste).

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь пользовательской генерацией событий [dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent). Для этого надо создать желаемое событие и отправить его, предварительно заглушив текущее событие через [stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

Небольшой пример вызова события нажатия клавиши при клике на окне.

```js
var el = document.getElementById("hello");

document.onclick = function(e){
    var event = new KeyboardEvent("keyup",{"key":"a"});
    document.dispatchEvent(event);
    e.stopPropagation();
}

document.onkeyup = function(e){
    console.log(e.key);
}
```

```html
<div id="hello">click me</div>
```

P.S. Если используете встроенные в браузер события, ознакомьтесь с их сигнатурой и параметрами перед использованием. Так как есть Event, [KeyboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent), MouseEvent, etc со своими собственными параметрами, которые надо заполнить перед вызовом события.

Comment: не совсем это нужно. Есть поле <span contenteditable="true"></span>
и когда начинаю вводить, например вместо буквы "a" ввело "A"